# Linking a template class using another template class (error LNK2001)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, templates, abstract-class

I implemented the "Strategy" design pattern using an Abstract template class, and two subclasses. Goes like this:

```
template <class T> 
class Neighbourhood {
public:
  virtual void alter(std::vector<T>& array, int i1, int i2) = 0;
};
```

and

```
template <class T> 
class Swap : public Neighbourhood<T> {
public:
  virtual void alter(std::vector<T>& array, int i1, int i2);
};
```

There's another subclass, just like this one, and `alter` is implemented in the cpp file. Ok, fine! Now I declare another method, in another class (including `neighbourhood` header file, of course), like this:

```
void lSearch(/*parameters*/, Neighbourhood<LotSolutionInformation> nhood);
```

It compiles fine and cleanly. When starting to link, I get the following error:

```
1>SolverFV.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall lsc::Neighbourhood<class LotSolutionInformation>::alter(class std::vector<class LotSolutionInformation,class std::allocator<class LotSolutionInformation> > &,int,int)" (?alter@?$Neighbourhood@VLotSolutionInformation@@@lsc@@UAEXAAV?$vector@VLotSolutionInformation@@V?$allocator@VLotSolutionInformation@@@std@@@std@@HH@Z)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a pretty rookie mistake. Since Neighbourhood is an abstract class, I must use it always as a pointer (**EDIT**: or a reference), since it must never be instantiated.

Changed signatures and it worked fine.

**EDIT**: Also, thanks to Neil, I know "it's got to be in the header".

Comment: In fact, you might prefer using references to Neighbourhood instead of pointers.

Comment: I would upvote if it wasn't saying you have to use pointers. What @Luc says

Answer (score 3):

> There's another subclass, just like
>   this one, and alter is implemented in
>   the cpp file.

No can do - it's got to be in the header.

Comment: Oh, yeah, this too. Since C++ is great for a plethora of things, I had even forgotten how it sucked as an OO language... :/